# Pickle (no file IO): TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: typeerror, pickle, python-3.6

I am getting this TypeError from object serialization alone, ie. no file IO involved (unlike other similar posts). One piece of the code is:

```
for itr in range(numiters):
    #Sample from proposal distribution
    d_star,Jratio,R_star,step = proposal(d_t,R_t,X,Y,alpha)
    #Compute the new posterior value, if necessary
    a_star = Pickle.dumps(d_star[:R_star+1])
    print(type(a_star))
    permsdic[a_star] = ...
```

and another is:

```
for perm in permsdic.keys():
    print(type(perm))
    print(perm)
    d_t = Pickle.loads(perm)
```

and yet I get the above error in: d_t = Pickle.loads(perm)
The output of print statements in the first block is:

class 'bytes'

and yet in 2nd block it is somehow:

class 'str'

b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x03K\x05K\x0cK\x00e.'

This is in Python 3.6 (I am trying to adapt an older Python library)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work by using eval() function, i.e. the following works

```
for perm in permsdic.keys():
    print(type(perm))
    print(perm)
    d_t = Pickle.loads(eval(perm))
```

I still don't understand why this is necessary...

Comment: had the same problem. eval in loads() solved it.